# how to make the textarea's width fixed but keep the height flexible CSS

Tags: html, css, textarea

how to make the textarea's width fixed but keep the height flexible CSS

so e.g. keep the default width of the textarea generated by the browser and disallow stretching to the right, but keep the height stretchable?

```
<textarea class="test"></textarea>

.test {
width:
height:}
```

Comment: `width: 100px; height:auto` or whatever....

Comment: what do you mean by "width generated by the browser"? That really depends on how the width is determined. You might give it a wrapper and tell the textbox to be 100% width, height auto, and maybe combine it with `resize: vertical`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with [**resize**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize) property value set to `vertical`

Check the browser compatibility table: [**Can I use resize**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)

```css
.test {
  resize: vertical;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="test"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

.test{max-width:300px;}